# Converting query string to an associative array in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.7

How to convert query string to an associative array in `symfony2`?

Im new to `symfony2`.
I googled it for couple of hours but there is no straightforward answer (example).
Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$request->query->all();
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html

A Symfony request stores the superglobals in ParameterBag instances. You can see more about the ParameterBag API here:

http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html